# Update field taking values sequentially from another table

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I want to link two tables with no previous relation between them by picking a value from one into the other one.

So my tables are:

Codes:

| id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |

People:

| id | type | code_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | X |
| 2 | 2 | X |
| 3 | 7 | X |

I want to update the table `people` picking values from the table `codes`. Whenever an item from `people` has the condition `label=2`, then it needs to pick a different id from `codes`. There are more codes in "codes" than people in "people", so every person can have a different code.

So that for example the result is:

| id | type | code_id | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | updated with one value from codes table |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | updated with another value from codes table |
| 3 | 7 | X | not updated, since `type<>2` |

I have tried by using an INNER JOIN like this, but it does not work when using the `WHERE` filter:

```
UPDATE people A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id FROM codes WHERE label=2) B
USING (id)
SET A.code_id=B.id
WHERE A.type=2;
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have prepared a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80a3e) to test with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE codes (id int auto_increment primary key, label int);
CREATE TABLE people (id int auto_increment primary key, type int, code_id int);
INSERT INTO codes VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2);
INSERT INTO people (id,type) VALUES (1,2),(2,2),(3,7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to work using [CURSORs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) (so you can step through the codes table line-by-line copying a result across each time). Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatecodes()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE a,b INT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM codes WHERE label = 2;
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM people WHERE type = 2;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


OPEN cur1;
OPEN cur2;

read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO a;
  FETCH cur2 INTO b;
  IF done THEN 
    LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;

  UPDATE people SET code_id = a WHERE id = b;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
CLOSE cur2;

END
```

Then just

```
CALL updatecodes();
```

If I've got the linking right, there should be an updated SQL Fiddle here: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25d35/2)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much for pointing in the good direction (no basic query but cursors)... and getting there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this...

```
 SELECT x.id,x.type, y.id code_id
   FROM 
      ( SELECT a.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM people a
          JOIN people b
            ON b.type = a.type
           AND b.id <= a.id
         GROUP  
            BY type, id
      ) x
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT a.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM codes a
          JOIN codes b
            ON b.label = a.label
           AND b.id <= a.id
         GROUP  
            BY label
             , id
      ) y
     ON y.label = x.type 
    AND y.rank = x.rank;
```

...or rewritten as an UPDATE...

```
 UPDATE people p
   JOIN
      ( SELECT a.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM people a
          JOIN people b
            ON b.type = a.type
           AND b.id <= a.id
         GROUP  
            BY type, id
      ) x
     ON x.id = p.id
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT a.*
             , COUNT(*) rank
          FROM codes a
          JOIN codes b
            ON b.label = a.label
           AND b.id <= a.id
         GROUP  
            BY label
             , id
      ) y
     ON y.label = x.type 
    AND y.rank = x.rank
    SET p.code_id = y.id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting your answer. To be honest I went for the other answer as I read it before. I still have to check this one, but anyway +1 for it and thanks for the time.